# Where is the 'on selected polygons only' setting in Processing tools?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

Does anyone know where the geoprocess 'on selected polygons only' functionality has gone? I can't seem to find it (Vector>Geoprocessing Tools). As far as I can remember old fTools geoprocessing tools had this functionality - for some reason in the blanket replacement this has disappeared. Are there any workarounds? It's really frustrating to have so much useful functionality removed.

Edit: I'm using QGIS 2.16.0

Comment: Have you tried it before posting here? Processing uses "selected features only" by default. Can be configured in the Processing Options.

Comment: I have - I clipped to a shapefile with one polygon selected and it didn't work. Use only selected features is definitely selected in my Processing Options. I will attempt it again now.

Comment: Installed version 2.16.1 and it now works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In old version you have this option in Geoprocess dialogs.

[image]

But If you are using QGIS 2.16.0,check the Processing Options,and check "Use Only Selected features"
[image]

Example with two polygon layers and the result is correct.

[image]