# Create a buffer for polygons that meet a condition with QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, buffer

I have a layer with polygons, and I want to make a buffer but only for the ones that meet a condition (`"MUNICIPIO"=5`). When I make a fixed distance buffer, it makes a buffer for all the polygons in the layer. Is there a way to make a buffer only for the polygons I want?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205916/where-is-the-on-selected-polygons-only-setting-in-processing-tools/205931#205931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select by Expression` from the attribute table to select polygons of "MUNICIPIO"=5 and use Fixed Distance Buffer for the selected polygons.

Use Fixed Distance Buffer from SAGA tools which you can find it from `Processing toolbox -> SAGA -> Vector General tools -> Fixed Distance Buffer`. It should work.

Make sure that Use only selected features option is checked from the Processing Option. It should be checked by default.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where can I find the Processing options window?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use a `Virtual Layer`.

Choose `Add/Edit Virtual Layer` in the `Manage Layers Toolbar`, import your layer and use a query like:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry, 100) FROM your_layer WHERE MUNICIPIO=5
```